# Jquery not binding event onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables

```
(function() {
var bgOn;
$(".ContainingBox").on('hover', function() {
    function() { 
    bgOn = $(this).css("background-color");
            $(this).css("background-color", "#e5fff8");
      }, function() {
      $(this).css("background-color", bgOn);
      }
 });
})();
```

I want to bind an event for hover. This code worked fine when I did not wrap it in the anonymous function, and used `.hover()` . However, we have a requirement to not use global variables. So i need to bind the event!

Is this not possible?

Comment: There is no `hover` event, jQuery did at some point create strange `hover()` methods, but what you're looking for is really `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

Comment: Just for the record, your title is misleading. There is an event called 'onload' and what you said was jQuery is not binding that event. What you meant was that it wasn't binding *an* event *when the page loads* i.e. 'on(space)load' (implied) *of the page*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has syntax errors, specifically `on()` does not accept multiple callbacks etc.
Also, there is no native `hover` event, you should use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` instead

```
$(".ContainingBox").on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $(this).data('bg', $(this).css("background-color"));
        $(this).css("background-color", "#e5fff8");
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).css("background-color", $(this).data('bg'));
    }
});
```

Using jQuery's `data()`, and not a single variable,  will remember the background color for each element

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/eww32aen/)

Comment: is using .data, technically a global variable though?

Comment: @christopherclark - no, it's technically not a global variable, as the data is stored in an object somewhere under the global `window.jQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

try this....

```
(function() {
       var bgOn;
       $(".ContainingBox").on('mouseover', function() {
          function() { 
             bgOn = $(this).css("background-color");
             $(this).css("background-color", "#e5fff8");
          }, function() {
               $(this).css("background-color", bgOn);
             }
       });
 })();
```

Comment: That's more of a comment than an answer, not to mention it's already been said